# Drupal 8: Multistep ajaxified form in a modal window

Tags: modal-dialog, drupal-8, multi-step

Task description:

I need to open modal window by url location hash i.e.

www.example.com#overlay=my-multistep-form (pretty the same what D7 overlay module does). This window should contain multi-step ajaxified form,

so I use

```
Drupal.behaviors.rf_overlay = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        // get overlay url
        if (location.hash.indexOf('#overlay') >= 0) {
            var event = { data: {} };
            // Special route for multistep forms
            if (location.hash.indexOf('#overlay=become-a-sales-partner') >= 0) {
                event.data.url = '/overlay/partner-form';
                openMultistepFormModal(event);
            }
        }

        function openMultistepFormModal(event) {
            Drupal.ajax({
                url: event.data.url,
                success: function(response) {
                    var content = '';
                    for (var i in response) {
                        if (response[i].data != undefined) {
                            content += response[i].data;
                        }
                    }
                    $('.modal-body').empty();
                    var $overlayContent = $('<div>' + content + '</div>').appendTo('.modal-body');
                    Drupal.dialog($overlayContent, {});
                    $("#drupal-modal").addClass('overlay-' + event.data.url).modal();
                }
            }).execute();
        }

    }
};
```

I also have form controller at /overlay/partner-form route, so it returns form array according to specified step

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $options = array()) {
  $step = in_array($form_state->get('step'), array(1, 2)) ? $form_state->get('step') : 1;
  $form_state->set('step', $step);

  switch ($step) {
    case 1:
      return $this->stepOnePerson($form, $form_state);
    case 2:
      return $this->stepTwoCompany($form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

When I submit this form it doesn't load step 2 form after ajax call.

My question is: is there some good code example or tutorial on this topic? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/

Comment: Thanks, VJamie, the article was helpful, but I still have problem with the step 2 form: it is not ajax-initialized, so it redirects me to some page on submit. It looks like Drupal.attachBehaviors are not attached to the ajax-loaded form. I had all kinds of experiment trying to attach those behaviors, with no luck, however...

Comment: Hi! Got the same problem, did you find any solution?